# How to access object property when property name contains - (hyphen)

Tags: php, oop, syntax

I need an escape sequence for `-` or the minus sign for php. The object has a name-value pair where the name happens to be having `-` between 2 words.

I can't do this using `\` the standard escape sequence (`-` isn't anyways documented).

I can store the name in a `$myvariable` which can be used but out of curiosity is it possible to do the following?

```
$myobject->myweird-name
```

This gives an Error because of `-`

Comment: Can you show us the code you have? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: What hinders you specifically to just escape it?

Comment: Everything is possible to do, but you need to add more info or examples.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
$myobject->{'myweird-name'};
```

Answer (score 10):

If you need to look up an index, there are a couple of ways of doing it:

```
// use a variable
$prop = 'my-crazy-property';
$obj->$prop;

// use {}
$obj->{'my-crazy-property'};

// get_object_vars (better with a lot of crazy properties)
$vars = get_object_vars($obj);
$vars['my-crazy-property'];

// you can cast to an array directly
$arr = (array)$obj;
$arr['my-crazy-property'];
```

If you need to work within a string (which is not your best idea, you should be using manual concatenation where possible as it is faster and parsed strings is unnecessary), then you should use {} to basically escape the entire sequence:

```
$foo = new stdClass();
$foo->{"my-crazy-property"} = 1;
var_dump("my crazy property is {$foo->{"my-crazy-property"}}";
```

---

Since you mentioned that this is LinkedIn's API which, I believe, has the option of returning XML, it might be faster (and possibly cleaner/clearer) to use the XML method calls and not use the objects themselves. Food for thought.